# Visual Studio Unable to read the NuGet.Config file - just downloaded for mac

Tags: visual-studio

[image]

I Get this error whenever I open a new project on visual studio for mac. I just installed the software and don't understand why it can't locate the folder. How do I fix this?

Comment: any help or ideas are apricated

Comment: Does the file exist and is it readable? (It's just an XML document, actually)

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 - Enter to the path message: /Users/username/.config/Nuget/

Step 2 - Right click into a Nuget.config file and get info

Step 3 - in sharing and permission click in plus(+) button and add your user with read and write permission

Step 4 - Close and open Visual Studio